# Check if many-to-many relationship exists before insert or delete

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sqlalchemy, constraints

I have 3 tables

For example:

```
Book
id
title
```

```
Tag
id
name
```

```
BookTag
book_id
tag_id
```

The goal to disallow having Book without Tag. i.e. when I try insert/delete data I need something to check on database level that Book has at least one Tag through many-to-many. If such validation fails it should throw `constaint violation error` or some sort of that. How should I implement that? Can it be reached by `check constraint` or should I create some `trigger`, if so then how?

please help me. thanks for your help in advance

Comment: your welcome! please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and get tour here : https://stackoverflow.com/tour then edit your question for give good answers and feedback

your can add create tables script for this question

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce this at the pure database level by adding a foreign key in the `book` table that points back to a tag (any tag) in the `book_tag` table. As of now, your database model looks like:

```
create table book (
  id int primary key not null,
  title varchar(50)
);

create table tag (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(50)
);

create table book_tag (
  book_id int not null,
  book_tag int not null,
  primary key (book_id, book_tag)
);
```

Now, add the extra foreign key that points back to a tag:

```
alter table book add column a_tag int not null;

alter table book add constraint fk1 foreign key (id, a_tag)
  references book_tag (book_id, tag_id) deferrable initially deferred;
```

Now when you insert a book, it can temporarily not have a tag, but only while the transaction hasn't finished yet. You need to insert a tag before committing. If you don't the constraint will fail, the transaction will rollback, and the insert won't happen.

**Note**: Please notice that this requires the use of deferrable constraints (look at `deferrable initially deferred`), something that is part of the *SQL Standard* but seldomly implemented. Fortunately, PostgreSQL does.

**EDIT - Adding an example**

Considering the previous modified tables you can try inserting a book without tags (will fail) and with tags (succeeding) as shown below:

```
insert into tag (id, name) values (10, 'classic');
insert into tag (id, name) values (12, 'action');
insert into tag (id, name) values (13, 'science fiction');

-- begin transaction
insert into book (id, title, a_tag) values (1, 'Moby Dick', 123);
commit; -- fails

-- begin transaction
insert into book (id, title, a_tag) values (2, 'Frankenstein', 456);
insert into book_tag (book_id, book_tag) values (2, 10);
insert into book_tag (book_id, book_tag) values (2, 13);
update book set a_tag = 10;
commit; -- succeeds
```

Comment: I understood about transaction and `deferrable initially deferred` thing. Can you please explain `a_tag` fk? how it will work? maybe some example? Thanks.

Comment: @rastilization I added an example for both cases.